# why is my markdwon table in jupyter notebook not rendering correctly?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, jupyter-console

im trying to render this table where it contain a single

column , the first row with the header and a second like the following

| Data Science Tools |
| --- |
| apache hadoop | Rstudio |

it doesnt render , it renders like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJmGv.png)
how can i correct it ?

i tried to change it to this markdown
|Data Science Tools|
| --- | --- | --- |
|apache hadoop|apache spark|Rstudio|

now it doesnt render at all
how can i fix this please